# Parse json string into scala case class in java

Tags: java, scala, spring-mvc, jackson, case-class

I have a small spring(mvc) web application. This application has dependency on one scala module, which has a `case class` MessageCommand. I want to convert the JSON String into MessageCommand Case class using `Jackson`.

Is this possible?

I am using Spring 4, Jackson-asl 1.9, Scala 2.11 Case class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can. But you need to tweak some things in case class:

```
case class Message(@BeanProperty var num:Int, @BeanProperty var name:String){
    def this() = this(-1,null)
}

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

val mapper = new ObjectMapper
val json = """{"num":1,"name":"Di Caprio"}"""

scala> val user = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[Message])
user: Message = Message(1,Di Caprio)
```

If you cannot tweak the case class, then it gets a bit difficult and untidy

Comment: What s the way if I can not edit the scala class? Do I need to write a simple java class and then set the values into the case class from the java class manually?

Comment: I googled and found this: https://github.com/mesosphere/jackson-case-class-module Not sure on how good it is.

Comment: I have to do this in Java, not scala. I mean I need to parse a string in java and convert as Scala Case class

Comment: I applied the answer you have provided and changed the scala code. that is working fine.

Comment: If you are doing it in Java. Things still remain the same: `ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper(); m.readValue(json, Message.class)` :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was trying to avoid those 2 lines by utilizing the spring-jackson integration which automatically converts to the object. Anyway, I was able to do it with the answer u suggested.